# How to add an Object to an ArrayList

Tags: java, adventure

I recently changed my Locale constructor to take in an array called Item instead of just an item name and now I'm having some difficulties with taking an item in my game. This is a text adventure game where the player can move around the map and pick up items that are in the rooms. I am getting the error: "The method add(String) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (Item)". I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Thank you for all help!

Here is my code:

```
static int currentLocation = player1.currentRoom;

//Items {itemName, itemDes}
 static Item[] items = {
         new Item ("map","A layout of your house."),
         new Item ("battery", "A double A battery."),
         new Item ("flashlight", "A small silver flashlight."),
         new Item ("key", "This unlocks some door in your house."),

 };

//Locations {roomName, description, Item}
 static Locale[] locales = { 
         new Locale("bedroom","You see the outline of a bed with your childhood stuffed bear on it.",items[0]),
         new Locale("hallway","A carpeted floor and long pictured walls lie ahead of you.",null),
         new Locale("kitchen","The shining surface of your stove reflects the pale moonlight coming in the window over the sink.",items[1]),
         new Locale("bathroom","You find yourself standing in front of a mirror, looking back at yourself.",items[2]),
         new Locale("living room","You stub your toe on the sofa in the room, almost falling right into the TV.",null),
         new Locale("dining room","You bump the china cabinet which holds your expensive dishes and silverware.",items[3]),
         new Locale("office","The blinking light from the monitor on your desk can be seen in the dark",null),
         new Locale("library","The smell of old books surrounds you.",null),
         new Locale("basement","You reach the top of some stairs and upon descending down, you find the large metal generator.",null),   
 };

//Take
          else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("T")){
              Locale locale = locales[currentLocation];
              // check if the locale has an item.
              if(locale.item != null){
                  // create an "ArrayList" with all the items from the players inventory or an empty one if the inventory is "null"
                  ArrayList<String> inventory;
                  if(player1.inventory != null){
                      inventory = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(player1.inventory));
                  }
                  else{
                      inventory = new ArrayList();
                  }
                  // add the item to the list and set the list as the player's inventory by converting it to an array.
                  inventory.add(locale.item);
                  player1.inventory = inventory.toArray(new String[inventory.size()]);
                  System.out.println("\tA " + locale.item + " was added to the inventory");
                  System.out.println("\n\tYou can view your inventory by pressing 'I'.");
                  System.out.println("\n\tFive points have also been added to your score.");
                  player1.score += 5;
                  System.out.println("\n\tThis is your current score: "+player1.score);
                  locale.item = null;
              }
              // this locale doesn't have an item.
              else{
                  System.out.println("\tThere is no item to pick up");
              }
              break;
          }//End of Take
```

This is my Locale class:

```
public class Locale {

//Locale must have name, description, and Item
public static int roomNumber;
public String roomName;
public String description;
public Item item;


public Locale(String roomName, String description, Item item){
    this.roomName = roomName;
    this.description = description;
    this.item = Item;
}
}
```

This is my Item class:

```
public class Item {
//item must have a name and a description (both strings)
public String itemName;
public String itemDes;

public Item (String itemName, String itemDes){
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.itemDes = itemDes;
}
}
```

Comment: try inventory.add() for adding single object and inventory.addAll() for adding a list

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Why does your constructor expect an Object, if you actually need an Item? Just change the constructor to accept an Item instance instead. Also, Java naming conventions prefer lowercased variable names, so I would suggest changing public Object Item to public Item item.

Comment: I got a little confused and I now changed the Item in the constructor to be Item item, but in the take method I am getting the error: "The method add(String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments Item"

Answer (score 0):

item[i] references an Item object. If Item is a parameter for your Locale constructor i don't see why this wouldn't work. Are there any specific error messages?

Comment: This is the error message: "The method add(String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments( Item)"

Comment: Two things i noticed is that in your Locale constructor Item shouldn't be capitalized because there is no "Item" field, only an "item" field. Also i'm not sure if you need to be declaring some of this stuff static. Are you even using any arraylists in your program? Without know exactly how you're organizing things it's gonna be hard to help. I assume you're putting everything in separate classes in eclipse/whatever ide you're using? Just to make sure your main method can see the other classes maybe you want to do something simple like make an item (Item myItem = new Item("stuff","stuff");

Comment: I am using an arrayList of Strings for my inventory and adding the item to it when it is taken from the room with the command 'T'. Each of the four items in the game have their item name(itemName) and item description (itemDes). I'm trying to add the item to inventory but am running into an issue when it comes to adding the item that is in the current locale. It worked before when it was just a single string like "map" that represented an item, but now since it is an array I'm a little lost.

Comment: You should create an arraylist of items then if you want to store items, instead of strings. ArrayList<Item> inventory = new ArrayList<Item>();

Comment: If you want to add the string representation of an Item you could do do something like add(item){inventory.add(item.name);}

Comment: Thats just a standard array, and ArrayList is something different

Comment: I think i see what youre talking about ill have to go over your code some more when i get a chance. In the meantime try changing the it to ArrayList<Item> (if ots storing Items) where you are creating the arraylist and see if that works.

Comment: Am I correct in saying now that I must change player.inventory to an array list of Item because of this line:  inventory = new ArrayList<Item>(Arrays.asList(player1.inventory));

Comment: Np. If that fixed it you mind giving me an upvote? Thanks :)

Comment: inventory = new ArrayList<Item>(Arrays.asList(player1.inventory)); This part is not working now as the player1.inventory is not an ArrayList<Item>. It seems this affects much of my code. I'll try to find a way around it